# Scala - Use Variable in Java String

Tags: json, scala, variables

Does anyone know a way around this.  I am looking to insert the `prev_yr` variable into the below json string in place of the hard coded date of 01-01-2021.  I have tried several solutions I have seen online but have not been successful so far.  I tried curly bracket and adding `+` around the variable. I may be setting it up wrong:

```
val prev_yr:String=format.format(cal.getTime)

val getsomething=
        """
        {
          "date": "startdt > 01-01-2021",
          "max_results" : "10"
        }
        """
```

Comment: `getSomeString.replace("01-01-2021", prev_yr)`? Although if you find yourself doing this a lot, you may want to use an appropriate json library.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably setting it wrong :) If you show us what you tried, and explain what problems you had with it, then someone might be able to spot what exactly it is that you are "setting wrong" :)

Comment: Here are 3 different ways I tried to set it
"date": "startdt > {{prev_yr}}"
"date": "startdt > "'"prev_yr"'"
"date": "startdt > +prev_yr+

Comment: As far as what went wrong I feed this .json string into a put request.  Once the post request sees the character it isnt interpreting the date.  I receive an error back saying "Unexpected character'

Comment: @user3492735 check [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```scala
val prev_yr:String=format.format(cal.getTime)

val getsomething =
  s"""
    {
      "date": "startdt > $prev_yr",
      "max_results" : "10"
    }
    """
```